# Returning JS containing HTML from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a PHP foreach loop to create JS variables, containing an HTML entered from a WYSIWYG field.

```
foreach($Entries as $Entry){

    //$$WYSIWYG_Field calls a database field of pure HTML entered via WYSIWYG field.//

    $Field_Cured=addslashes($WYSIWYG_Field);

    $WYSIWYG_Return=

<<<HTML
        '<p><strong>Statement: </strong>$Field_Cured</p>' 
HTML;

    $Variables.=

<<<HTML
        var N_$Entry = '<div class="content">' +
                    '<span><strong>Name: </strong>$Name</span><br>' +  $WYSIWYG_Return +
                    '</div>';
HTML;

}
```

I am then using those created JS $Variables to set them as innerHTML when called in a JS function.

My question is robustness based, is it enough to use addslashes() or would there be some characters, if present in the HTML, will break the JS?

**In other words:
How compatible is PHP's addslashes(); with the JS syntax?**

Comment: I dont see any JS in your code snippet? If you save the html in some kind of string variable using `"` or `'` as their quotation marks, addslashes should be fine: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php. As long as it's not used for security relevant things

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, web servers typically execute the server-side files before any client-side scripting would execute on web browsers. It depends on `php.ini` and other configuration settings whether there may be warning or errors generated from PHP script that may affect JavaScript on the front-end.

There is [PHP DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to help generate HTML from server-side for JavaScript. Going that route, you would have flexibility about managing data between back-end and front-end.

As a simple example, [`<element onload="function">`](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_onload.asp), could trigger a JavaScript function on web browsers.

Your code is unclear about the purpose to use String-delimiter and storing JS variable in PHP.